# How to show progress while uploading data in IntentService in Android

Tags: android, android-intentservice

I'm uploading a large image that is converted to `Base64` `String` in a `IntentService`. I have splitted the String, to not send all the parts on one time.

In my `IntentService` so, I'm uploading that parts to the Server.
This happens in the background. If the user wants to know how far the uploading process is, I want to add an Item in the `Navigation Drawer` to start an Activity that shows the progress.

Is it anyway possible to show this progress?

I would be really thankful if someone can tell me how to do this.

I've read somewhat about `BroadcastReceiver`. But I don't understand how that works and I really don't know if it will matter my concern.

Thanks for any help!

Kind Regards!

Comment: You can use `BroadcastReceiver` if you don't need to send it too often. The problem with a broadcast is that you can't technically guarantee which the order they will come in. You could implement messaging inside the app by using something like EventBus (https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), however I suggest you subscribe through an interface if you want to send over the progress quite often. That's the easiest way to do this.

Comment: So thats the only way I can do it? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: That's three ways, please see the edit

Comment: Oh yes I see. I hope I can implement it like I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Ofcourse you can use broadcast receivers for this. There is another approach. You can use `ResultReceiver` class to achieve this. Create a CustomResultReceiver class

```
public class CustomResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {

        private Receiver receiver;

        public CustomResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public interface Receiver {
            void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData);

        }

        public void setReceiver(Receiver receiver) {
            this.receiver = receiver;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {

            if (receiver != null) {
                receiver.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
            }
        }

    }
```

In your activity, implement the receiver

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity implements CustomResultReceiver.Receiver {
        public CustomResultReceiver mReceiver;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            mReceiver = new CustomResultReceiver(new Handler());
            mReceiver.setReceiver(this);

            //pass the receiver to the service
            intent.putExtra("SOME_TAG", mReceiver);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            // here you can get the values from the bundle and display the progress accordingly
        }
    }
```

Now in your service, whenever you want to send any data to the activity, you can simple do it by

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("SOME_TAG");
        Bundle b= new Bundle();
        //put your progress value in the bundle
        b.putString("SOME_DATA", dataValue);
        receiver.send(RESULT_CODE, b);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I would suggest you to upload you image using AsyncTask. Here you will get the benefit of onProgressUpdate() method. What you need to do is:

1. Create an interface, having a method, say onUploadingUpdate.
2. Implement that interface in your activity.
3. Create your AsyncTask class for uploading your image file.
4. Call this AsyncTask in your activity using its constructor.
5. In AsyncTask's onProgressUpdate() method call the interface's method. This will give you the progress in activity.
6. In Activity use this progress to update progress in your navigation drawer.

If you don't understood, post your code. I'll do it for you.